# grid layout as background, not using body tag

Tags: html, css

I want my background to be a grid. I found this:

html:

```
<div id="content"> </div>
```

css:

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
body {
    width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
    background-color: #434343;
    background-image:linear-gradient(#434343, #282828);
}
#content{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:       linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent);
  height:100%;
  background-size:50px 50px;
}
```

though it only works when a body tag is used. I want to be able to change `body` to something like #contentbody, though this does not work (does not display a grid anymore).

I tried making the position of #content absolute and z-index to -1, and making the background color of divs on top of it transparent, but this did not work either. can anyone help me?

So I essentially have 2 questions, and either one can be answered (or both if youd like):

1. how can I have a grid background with a custom tag like #contentbody (and not `body`)
2. how can I overlay divs on top of a `position:aboslute; z-index:-1 grid` background and show that grid?

https://jsfiddle.net/7d805qut/

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Your grid  background seems to be working fine in the fiddle. Not sure why you think it isn't. As for positioning elements on the grid - https://jsfiddle.net/qhgroe2w/

Answer (score 0):

Simply consider multiple background like you are already doing:

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
}
#content{
    background:
     linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%,  transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%,  transparent 77%), 
     
     linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, transparent 77%),
     
     linear-gradient(#434343, #282828);
  height:100%;
  background-size:50px 50px,50px 50px,auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"> </div>
```